# Find co-occurrences of two lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have got two lists. The first one contains names and second one names and corresponding values. The names of the first list in a subset of the name of the name of the second lists. The values are a true or false. I want to find the co-occurrences of the names of both lists and count the true values. My code:

```
data1 = [line.strip() for line in open("text_files/first_list.txt", 'r')]
ins = open( "text_files/second_list.txt", "r" )  # the "r" is not really needed - default 
parseTable = []

for line in ins:
   row = line.rstrip().split(' ')  # <- note use of rstrip()
   parseTable.append(row)

new_data = []
indexes = []
for  index in range(len(parseTable)):
   new_data.append(parseTable[index][0])
   indexes.append(parseTable[index][1])
in1 =return_indices_of_a(new_data, data1)

def return_indices_of_a(a, b):
  b_set = set(b)
  return [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v in b_set] #return the co-occurrences
```

I am reading both text files which containing the lists, i found the co-occurrences and then I want to keep from the parseTable[][1] only the in1 indices . Am I doing it right? How can I keep the indices I want? My two lists:

```
['SITNC', 'porkpackerpete', 'teensHijab', '1DAlert', 'IsmodoFashion',....
[['SITNC', 'true'], ['1DFAMlLY', 'false'], ['tibi', 'true'], ['1Dneews', 'false'], ....
```

Comment: How about making a `dict` out of the second list?

Comment: Please add more detail about your suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one liner to get the matches:

```
matches = [(name, dict(values)[name]) for name in set(names) if name in dict(values)]
```

and then to get the number of true matches:

```
len([name for (name, value) in matches if value == 'true'])
```

**Edit**

You might want to move `dict(values)` into a named variable:

```
value_map = dict(values)
matches = [(name, value_map[name]) for name in set(names) if name in value_map]
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you're creating as many `dict`s as `len(names)`.

Comment: @bereal I was also wondering about this, I don't think there's any way of declaring named variables in a list comprehension... style over efficiency :p

Comment: @Daniel: It's not pretty, but `[(...) for d in [dict(values)] for name in ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just the sum of `true` values, then use `in` operator and list comprehension:

```
In [1]: names = ['SITNC', 'porkpackerpete', 'teensHijab', '1DAlert', 'IsmodoFashion']

In [2]: values = [['SITNC', 'true'], ['1DFAMlLY', 'false'], ['tibi', 'true'], ['1Dneews', 'false']]

In [3]: sum_of_true = len([v for v in values if v[0] in names and v[1] == "true"])

In [4]: sum_of_true
Out[4]: 1
```

To get also indices of co-occurrences, this one-liner may come in handy:

```
In [6]: true_indices = [names.index(v[0]) for v in values if v[0] in names and v[1] == "true"]

In [7]: true_indices
Out[7]: [0]
```

Comment: Since I want to create a precision recall diagram I need to get also the co-occurrences matrix.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, one is what Andrey suggests (you may want to convert `names` to `set`), or, alternatively, convert the second list into a dictionary:

```
mapping = dict(values)
sum_of_true = sum(mapping[n] for n in names)
```

The latter `sum` works because `bool` is essentially `int` in Python (`True == 1`).